# Flutter how to handle Image.network error (like 404 or wrong url)

Tags: flutter, http-status-code-404

How to handle `Image.network` when the url is wrong or the destination leads to 404.

for example try

```
Image.network('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92')
```

Comment: I think https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18424 was supposed to allow that, but I didn't have a closer look yet myself.

Answer (score 122):

I have handled the network image issue related to 404 by using an errorBuilder.

```
Image.network('Your image url...',
    errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        return Text('Your error widget...');
    },
),
```

[errorBuilder property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html)

Comment: Beautiful! This error builder got added recently in early 2020. Before I had to use 'precacheImage' to check if the url works which really complicated the code.

Comment: I'm getting the exception error if the user goes back to the screen before loading the image. Only happened in the case if URL returns 404 otherwise all good. How to prevent that?

Comment: It doesn't work when the object is not found in firebase storage.

Comment: @ShahabuddinVansiwala yes the same error I had, did you find any solution ?

Comment: I added errorBuilder, but still meet this error in method _loadAsync line 147, rethrow, my flutter version >=2.19.0-255.2.beta <3.0.0, my IDE is vscode.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, works great, clean and unit test safe.

Answer (score 24):

**UPDATE**: Look at the new accurate way which uses an inbuilt method, answered by @Niraj Phutane [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64531787/8608146) which requires no plugins.

---

#### old answer (before errorbuilder existed)

I recommend using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) which gives an option to add a placeholder image and also an error widget in case of a 404 or 403.

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
   imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
   placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

**Edit:** If your app crashes when url is a 404, the [faq](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image#faq) has an entry regarding this, please file a bug report with a reproducible example to cached_network_image on github.

Comment: `CachedNetworkImage` causes the app to freeze when the status code is 404

Comment: CachedNetworkImage still throws an Exception when 404

Comment: @Jorge did you find the solution for 404?

Comment: I'm getting the exception error if the user goes back to the screen before loading the image. Only happened in the case if URL returns 404 otherwise all good. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 15):

You can display image from assets when you found 404 or any other error while loading image.

What I have done is:

```
  FadeInImage(
      image: NetworkImage("imageUrl"),
      placeholder: AssetImage(
          "assets/images/placeholder.jpg"),
      imageErrorBuilder:
          (context, error, stackTrace) {
        return Image.asset(
            'assets/images/error.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
      },
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    )
```

Check `imageErrorBuilder` property.

Comment: not works when 404 is thrown

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `Network.image` use `NetworkImageWithRetry`

https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/flutter_image/latest/

Example:

```
var avatar = Image(
  image: NetworkImageWithRetry('http://example.com/avatars/123.jpg'),
);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `new` keyword beginning with Dart 2.0

Comment: Thanks, this was just copy and paste code from flutter repo

Comment: What does `NetworkImageWithRetry` do when you have 404 error?

Comment: By default just nothing. Mainly you won't get an exception and you end up with an empty image.

Comment: i am getting error "The method 'NetworkImageWithRetry' isn't defined.."

Comment: @krupeshAnadkat Add `flutter_image: ^1.0.0` to your `pubspek.yaml` file

Comment: @krupesh-anadkat also add the import `import 'package:flutter_image/network.dart';`

Comment: Doesnt work. Still throws an exception when the resource is not found

Comment: @Jorge did you find any solution for crash when image not found 404. I. am facing the same issue, and app is crashing

Comment: @JenJose Yes, kind of. I use this: 
 static Future<Uint8List> loadBytes(String url, {Map<String, String> headers}) async {
    final Uri resolved = Uri.base.resolve(url);
    final Response response = await _httpClient.get(resolved, headers: headers);
    if (response == null || response.statusCode != 200) throw new Exception('HTTP request failed, statusCode: ${response?.statusCode}, $resolved');

    final Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;
    if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0) throw new Exception('NetworkImage is an empty file: $resolved');

    return bytes;
  }
Here you can catch

Comment: You can catch the Exception. I call this from initState in statefulWidgets and set the image widget this way. The only problem is that I couldnt make it work in combination with precacheImage (which is great because it starts loading before and the app behaves better

Comment: Thanks @Jorge , but I really need to cache images, otherwise, on scrolling it loads the images again and it seems to be less user-friendly.

Comment: @JenJose   For that have you considered AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin? You add it to your wrapper class and it keeps the state. Or if its a ListView you can configure it to keep the state:
But if you really need to use image caching (i.e. precacheImage) I am sure there is a way to combine precacheImage with byte loading. I was thinking about making a question about this exactly.

Answer (score 9):

Can use errorBuilder from Image.network or Image.asset

```
Image.network(
       path.image,
       width: 40,
       height: 40,
       errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
            StackTrace? stackTrace) {
         return const Text('');
       },
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ImageStream` to handle errors.

```dart
class CustomProductImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;

  const CustomProductImage(this.image);

  @override
  State<CustomProductImage> createState() => _CustomProductImageState();
}

class _CustomProductImageState extends State<CustomProductImage> {
  Widget mainWidget = const CircularProgressIndicator(); // Placeholder widget
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Image image = Image.network(widget.image, width: 50, height: 50);

    final ImageStream stream = image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty);

    stream.addListener(ImageStreamListener((info, call) {
      if (!completer) {
        completer = true;
        setState(() {
          mainWidget = image;
        });
      }
    }, onError: (dynamic exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
      print('Error is $exception , stack is $stackTrace');
      setState(() {
        mainWidget = const Icon(Icons.error); // Error Widget
      });
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return mainWidget;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not worked! thows exception when 404

Comment: @RajeshJr. can I get your image url?

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myprojectid/o/avatars%2F%2B919999999999.jpg?alt=media

Comment: @RajeshJr. Check now

Answer (score 3):

It's weird but you can't easily handle errors correctly with Image.Provider.
Use this handy package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage

Then in you code:

```
backgroundImage: AdvancedNetworkImage(
                    "YOUR IMAGE URL", 
                    fallbackAssetImage: "YOUR DEAULT ASSERT IMAGE eg:assets/default.png"
                  )
```

Comment: This is the only solution here that did not throw an error and hang my applicaiton. However in GitHub this package is marked as archived. Does anyone know why? It also fails to build on Flutter v1.2.x+

Comment: Sadly I ran into this error: https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/368 when trying to use it with Flutter 1.20.2. I still have no clue how to catch ALL errors that happen during loading a network image. :-(

Comment: this package is discontinued!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but, I solved it using the property 'imageErrorBuilder' of the FadeInImage class.

Here is a link about that: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html

The example was made for Image.network(), but it also work for FadeInImage.

Here's my code:

```
FadeInImage(
  imageErrorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print('Error Handler'); 
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
      child: Image.asset('assets/img/no_disponible.jpg'),
    );
  },
  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/img/loading.gif'), 
  image: NetworkImage(product.getImg()),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
),
```

The function of imageErrorBuilder will be execute for example, if the direction of the page doesn't exist.

I'm using Flutter 1.20.1

Comment: Throws exception when 404!

Answer (score 2):

I used the basic Image widget and added an error builder for errors and a loadingBuilder for loading status and for the actual image I used NetworkImageWithRetry so that it will try to load the image many times and give you an error at the end if it couldn't load the image.

```
Image(
      image: NetworkImageWithRetry(
      'http://ImageUrl.png',),
      errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrack) => Icon(Icons.error,),
      loadingBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrack) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    )
```

Comment: NetworkImageWithRetry -- is it a built in class?

Comment: It is part of flutter_image https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using **firebase storage**

*The above methods didn't help me at all.*
When the **object is not found** in firebase, I got an exception `"Null is not a type of  List<int>"`.
So I decided to verify if the Unit8List values are valid or not.
If it's valid then we are ready to show the image otherwise use any widgets as placeholder.

```
Future<String?> getImgUrl()async{
//Storage structre: avatars/+919999999999/avatar.jpg
//Permanent url of an image without tokens
//%2F means "/"
//%2B mans "+"

String imgUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yourFIrebaseProjectID/o/avatars%2F%2B919999999999%2Favatar.jpg?alt=media";

    try {
      Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgUrl)).load(imgUrl)).buffer.asUint8List();
      print("The image exists!");
      return imgUrl;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }




 Widget futureBulder(){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getImgUrl(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
bool error = snapshot.data==null;
//I use NetworkImage for demonstration purpose, use it whatever widget u want
        return CircleAvatar(
         backgroundImage: error? null : NetworkImage(snapshot.data!),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: The best solution here!

Comment: @emmanuelagarry Glad it helped you

Comment: This a great solution. But when I have a list of images displayed in a dropdown It causes a performance problem!

Comment: Absoultely it will cause a lag, In my case I use it only for avatars. Rest of the time I directly using Cached_network image and it works well. Make sure u have enabled CORS on your google cloud project.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem while learning flutter (not web). I found the solution after I tried all the non-working options that are given in this thread. They all print errors to the console if the address is wrong or the resource is not found. To play with my solution, you will need to install two plugins: [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) (the second plugin is only needed to open a link to this topic in the simulator). Be sure to read the up-to-date instructions for using plugins. How to play, you ask? Change the address in input Image URL field as you like! Please report bugs if you find them.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image 404',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const _problemDescriptionUrl =
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url';
  String imageUrl =
      'https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/90528830/018a6400-d879-11e9-92b4-492c61d9bc32';

  late Future<Widget> futureWidget;

  Future<Widget> fetchImage() async {
    if (imageUrl.startsWith('https://') &&
        Uri.tryParse(imageUrl) != null &&
        Uri.tryParse(imageUrl)!.hasAbsolutePath) {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
      if (response.statusCode == 200 &&
          (response.headers.keys.contains('content-type') &&
              !response.headers['content-type']!.contains('text/html'))) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the data.
        return Image.memory(response.bodyBytes, fit: BoxFit.cover);
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then
        return const Text('Failed to load Image');
      }
    }
    return const Text('Failed to load Image');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureWidget = fetchImage();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _launchUrl() async {
    if (!await launchUrl(Uri.tryParse(_problemDescriptionUrl)!)) {
      throw 'Could not launch $_problemDescriptionUrl';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Image.network Error 404 Solution'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: _launchUrl,
              child: const Text('The problem described here')),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200,
            child: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
              future: futureWidget,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return snapshot.data!;
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Form(
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
              initialValue: imageUrl,
              maxLines: 3,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  imageUrl = val;
                  futureWidget = fetchImage();
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there what i was looking for, but its temporary... its ignore 404 error exception and returning null.

```
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
      if (details.library == 'image resource service') {
        return;
      }
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(details);
    };
```

for more information
[errorBuilder throws exception for invalid image data #107416](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107416#issuecomment-1272514454)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this StatefulWidget for the same case, hope this helps!!!

```
    class NetworkImageHandlerViewer extends StatefulWidget {
      final String imageURL;
      bool errorFoundInImageLoad = false;
      NetworkImageHandlerViewer({
        Key key,
        @required this.imageURL,
      }) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _NetworkImageHandlerViewerState createState() =>
          _NetworkImageHandlerViewerState();
    }

    class _NetworkImageHandlerViewerState extends State<NetworkImageHandlerViewer> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              // color: Colors.black,
              child: (widget.errorFoundInImageLoad)
                  ? Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Unable To Fetch Image",
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          iconSize: 40,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (mounted) {
                                print("reloading image again");
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.errorFoundInImageLoad = false;
                                });
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Tap Refresh Icon To Reload!!!",
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : Image.network(
                      // widget.question.fileInfo[0].remoteURL,
                      widget.imageURL,
                      //
                      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) =>
                          (loadingProgress == null)
                              ? child
                              : Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                ),
                      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                        Future.delayed(
                          Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                          () {
                            if (mounted) {
                              setState(() {
                                widget.errorFoundInImageLoad = true;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                        );
                        return SizedBox.shrink();
                      },
                    ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 25),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image**

the plugin makes it easy to handle errors in Network image load

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:extended_image/extended_image.dart';

class ImageHolder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageHolder(
      {Key? key,
      required this.url,
      required this.imageHeight,
      required this.imageWidth})
      : super(key: key);

  final String url;
  final double imageHeight;
  final double imageWidth;

  @override
  _ImageHolderState createState() => _ImageHolderState();
}

class _ImageHolderState extends State<ImageHolder>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
        lowerBound: 0.0,
        upperBound: 1.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExtendedImage.network(
      widget.url,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      cache: true,
      loadStateChanged: (ExtendedImageState state) {
        switch (state.extendedImageLoadState) {
          case LoadState.loading:
            _controller.reset();
            return Image.asset(
              'assets/images/loading.gif',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            );
          case LoadState.completed:
            _controller.forward();
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: _controller,
              child: ExtendedRawImage(
                image: state.extendedImageInfo?.image,
                width: widget.imageWidth,
                height: widget.imageHeight,
              ),
            );
          case LoadState.failed:
            _controller.reset();
            state.imageProvider.evict();
            return Image.asset(
              'assets/images/failed.jpg',
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  placeholder: (context, url) =>
               Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => 
               Icon(Icons.error),
  imageUrl: image,
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
              )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like to rely on 3rd party packages except utterly necessary.. however, my approach of handling network image error is as below:

```
               FadeInImage(
                  imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                    return Image.asset(
                      "assets/placeholder.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      width: 150,
                    );
                  },
                  height: 100,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  placeholder: const AssetImage("assets/placeholder.png"),
                  image: Image.network(
                    getImageURL(selectedUser.profilePic!),
                  ).image,
                ),
```

as you can see, wrapping with fadeInImage gives us a nice trasition and at the same time, the errorBuilder catches the exception and returns a placeholder image... you can return an error image as well.. but the idea reamains the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to change how the dart VM handles the error. Provide the exception library string and the status code which can be any between 400-404. Such cases will just print the exception to the console in case of debug mode and won't be reported as a crash incase you have Firebase Crashlytics installed.

```
 FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
        if (details.library == 'image resource service' &&
            details.exception.toString().contains('400')) {
          debugPrint('Suppressed cachedNetworkImage Exception');
          return;
        }
        FlutterError.presentError(details);
      };
```

PS: Add this code in the main() function after `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensuredInitialized()`