# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI - Image.network

Tags: flutter, host

I am building an app in which I get image url from api and show them to user. This is my code:

```
 Image.network(
               news.urlToImage ??
               defaultPlaceholderImageUrl,
                      ),
```

Api sometimes doesn't provide url, so I displaye placeholder image, this part works fine. But I get the following error with one of the provided urls:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI https:////m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png
```

That [link](https:////m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png) works in browser. But not in app. How can I solve this?

Comment: `https:////` there is 4 slash, could you check if this is creating the issue?

Comment: @towhid that was causing the problem, thanks. But do I need to manually correct that?

Comment: if you have access to the database or somehow you can change that then you must do that. Otherwise, you have to fix it manually `replaceAll('////', '//')`

Comment: Well, I can't access, it is coming from API. But I would like to know that, how can use try-catch to prevent these kinds of errors and show user default image, if something us wrong

Comment: as far as I know, there is no native way to do it using `Image.network()`. But you can get help from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52568872/6413387

Comment: @towhid thank you, man. You are one big life saver

Comment: write these as answer, and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in the URL `https:////m.files.bbci....`. it has 4 `/` which was an invalid URL format for `Image.network()` widget. So far there is no native way to catch the exception, but you can use different libraries. You can learn more about the issue and possible solutions from this post.

[Flutter how to handle Image.network error (like 404 or wrong url)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52568872/6413387)