# Flutter error: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI Instance%20of%20'Future%3CString%3E'

Tags: flutter, firebase, url

I am trying to retrieve an string url from FirebaseFirestore.

My code for UI is as follows

```
Container(
                                                  height: 65,
                                                  width: 65,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                          width: 8,
                                                          color: const Color
                                                              .fromARGB(
                                                              255, 3, 54, 95)),
                                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                      color: Colors.black38),
                                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            22),
                                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                      imageUrl:
                                                          model.photoUrl,
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
```

The code is trying to access a variable from the provider file, which is as follows:

```
 photoUrl = AuthMethods().getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

//Authomethods file

```
Future<String> getPhotoUrl() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

final String photoUrl = (snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['photoUrl'];
return photoUrl;
// return photoUrl;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`getPhotoUrl()` is an async function and needs to be awaited to. It could only work if instead of

```
photoUrl = AuthMethods().getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

you instead write

```
photoUrl = await AuthMethods().getPhotoUrl();
```

Although this can only be called like that in another async which you might not have

Answer (score 1):

Before using your Url, you can call your Container by checking it to avoid asynchronous data pull problems. For example:

```
Widget get customImage {
    return renderUrl == null ?
      Container() :
      Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(renderUrl),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

Alternative:

> Add https:// before your uri

You can also review this answers: [Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI - Image.network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514827/invalid-arguments-no-host-specified-in-uri-image-network)

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.