# Flutter - How to catch an error when call a picture with a bad url with Image.Network

Tags: image, flutter, try-catch

I tried to call a picture with a bad url and show an image when failed...
but flutter throw an exception and try catch not working during run development.

```dart
var url = "http://badUrl.com"
try {
    return Image.network(
            url,
            width: pictureSize.width,
            height: pictureSize.height,
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                StackTrace stackTrace) {
              return Image.asset("assets/img/logo.png");
            },
    );
} catch (error) {
  return Image.asset("assets/img/logo.png");
}
```

I have already try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url/56513785) but it doesn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should adapt the `canLaunch` method which verify if your link is valid, to your example

```dart
if (canLaunch(url) != null) {
  launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a comprehensive solution to this you can use cached_image widget
https://pub.dev/packages/cache_image

This will help you out with a lot of exception cases