# How to validate image network with image 404 Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I need to show an image obtained from the internet(NetworkImage) and I want to validate that when the query status of that image is 404, show an image by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to handle Image.network error (like 404 or wrong url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url)

Answer (score 1):

Just have to use errorBuilder:

```
              Image.network(
                  'https://some_url.com/some_ime.jpeg',
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stack) {
                    if (error is NetworkImageLoadException && error.statusCode == 404) {
                      return Image.asset('404_image.png');
                    }
                    
                    return Image.asset('common_error.png');
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: I use this code and have the error in the _network_image_io.dart file

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you replaced the resource names?