# Handling 404 errors in Image.network

Tags: flutter, image, asynchronous

I have been reading some answers to this question at stackoverflow but no one has worked for me. For example this one: [Flutter how to handle Image.network error (like 404 or wrong url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url/64531787#64531787)

Here the code:

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: steamUsers.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: steamUsers[index].avatarUrl != null
                          ? Image.network(
                              steamUsers[index].avatarUrl!,
                              errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                return
                                  const Icon(Icons.person);
                              },
                            )
                          : const Icon(Icons.person),
                    ),
                    title: Text(steamUsers[index].accountName),
                    subtitle: Text(steamUsers[index].personName),
                  )),
```

How can I avoid flutter throwing an exception when picture is not found (404)? Notice I'm already using the errorBuilder property.

The exception dump is:

> HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404,
> https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/5e3a3f851ea968aa4a35fa454ddfe5acafe2ec3.jg

Comment: does it also happen on release mode?

Comment: What does the exception say, are you sure it is related to the 404 status?

Comment: @jraufeisen I have added the exception dump

Comment: @YeasinSheikh in release the exception is not thrown. Could you explain why is it? For me it is a very odd behaviour.

Comment: I think of it this way: Debug mode is used to show error during development. So it is natural. I don't know the actual reason, just found cases like this in the past. If I get a chance & remember, I will ask someone who might know the philosophy behind this.

Comment: use `cached_network_image`  ,  there `errorWidget` https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: @YeasinSheikh still not sensible to me. Debug builds offers tooling to find and debug code but core logic must not behave differnt from a release build.

Comment: yap, you are right,