# How handle with the invalid url exception | Image.network() flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

My application has an input that receives a link to retrieve an image from the internet, but if the user enters an invalid link, the app breaks.

I'm currently using `Image.network()` to make the image request.

How to handle this exception?

`child: ClipRRect( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), child: Image.network(imageController.text, fit: BoxFit.cover,) ),`

Error generated:
[Error generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAkZd.png)

Resolve the error and handle the thrown exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url) and use **error builder**.
You can also in your case check a variable using terniary operator:

```
child: imageController.text.isNotEmpty ? ClipRRect( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),   child: Image.network(imageController.text, fit: BoxFit.cover,), ) : const SizedBox(),
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

you have to future function  that check the url

```dart
try {
  Image.network('https://example.com/wrong-url.jpg');
} catch (e) {
  // Error handling code
  print('Error: $e');
  // Display a custom error message or fallback widget
  // For example:
  return Text('Invalid URL or Failed to load image');
}
```

and return it in FutureBuilder also You can use onErrorBuilder

```dart
Image.network(
      imageUrl,
      errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
        // Custom error widget to display when image loading fails
        return Text('Failed to load image');
      },
      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null)
          return child; // Image is still loading, return default placeholder
        return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Show a loading indicator
      },
    );
```

If you choose to use FutureBuilder you can handle all the error in your function

```dart
FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: yourFunction()
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          // Image loaded successfully
          return Image.network(imageUrl);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // Error occurred while loading image
          return Text('Failed to load image');
        } else {
          // Image still loading
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
```