# Question about NetworkImage and if else in flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement

I'm using Flutter's `CircleAvatar` with a `backgroundImage` property to display a network image. However, I want to implement a fallback mechanism, so that if the network image fails to load , it should display a local image stored on my computer.

I believe using an `if`-`else` statement can solve this problem, but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement it properly. Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this behavior?

```
 drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
      const DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        // child: Text('Drawer Header'),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://~~'),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `NetworkImage`, you can use [`Image.network`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html), which has an [`errorBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html) property.

So, instaed of:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://~~'),
        ),
```

Use:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
      child: Image.network(
        'https://placehold.co/600x400.png',
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          return  Image.asset('/assets/images/placeholder.png');
        },
      ),
    );
```

##### See also

- [Flutter how to handle Image.network error (like 404 or wrong url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url)