# ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///) error although my url link is correct

Tags: flutter

[image]I try to solve the problem although the user is in offline situation, to show local image ,but I get this error.how to solve it please help me .My url is not worng but get error .

```
  FadeInImage(
                      height: 250,
                      width: 300,
                      // here `bytes` is a Uint8List containing the bytes for the in-memory image
                      placeholder: AssetImage('images/profile.jpg'),
                      image: NetworkImage(user?.photoUrl ?? ''),
                    ),
```

Comment: What happens if you `user?.photoUrl`?

Comment: In app bar I also use this user?.photoUrl??' ' but It don't have no error. And get profileImage form backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... user is in offline situation, to show local image , but I get this error

The `placeholder` property is for while the image is *loading*, so after the image is fully loaded, you will still get an error in offline mode since it still tries to load a `NetworkImage` which won't work in *offline* mode.

to solve the problem, you can use an `Image.network`, which has an errorBuilder - and will get called if the network image isn't found, and then, you should load an *Asset* image.

```dart
FadeInImage(
              height: 250,
              width: 300,
              placeholder: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg'),
              image: Image.network(
                'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/493/200/300.jpg?hmac=grrcfhF-iSyQuaMEkd8b4OH6Gn2W3xm7dUL4-955Vxw',
                errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                    StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                  return Image.asset('/path/to/image.png');
                },
              ).image)
```

**See also**

- [Flutter how to handle Image.network error (like 404 or wrong url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568872/flutter-how-to-handle-image-network-error-like-404-or-wrong-url)